# Using setBorder does not have any affect with DefaultTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, grid, jtable, renderer

Some samples I found were modified to try and add padding to the cell using setBorder.  
Essentially trying to accomplish the same behavior as setIntercellSpacing but using the BorderFactory class instead. 
Based on the following code, there does not appear to be any effect on the cell padding. 
What step did I miss?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class EvenOddRowCellRenderer extends JFrame {
  DefaultTableModel tmodel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] { { "some", "text" },
      { "any", "text" }, { "even", "more" }, { "text", "strings" }, { "and", "other" },
      { "text", "values" } }, new Object[] { "Column 1", "Column 2" });


  public EvenOddRowCellRenderer() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JTable table = new JTable(tmodel);

    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyRenderer());
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
  }

  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new EvenOddRowCellRenderer().setVisible(true);
  }
}

class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
   public MyRenderer ()
   { 
       super();
       setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
   }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JTextField editor = new JTextField();
    if (value != null)
      editor.setText(value.toString());
    editor.setBackground((row % 2 == 0) ? Color.white : Color.cyan);
    return editor;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default renderer is a JLabel. You are setting the Border on the renderer, which is ok.

The problem is you create a second component, (the text field) and  you are returning the JTextField as the renderer component. You didn't add the Border to the text field. Get rid of the JTextField.

Just use `return this;` to return the label as the renderer.